# How to get all items through Spotipy including next page

Tags: python, spotipy

Using the [Spotipy python library](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.11.1/#api-reference) I'm trying to print out all my saved songs from Spotify.

Using the following code I'm able to print out all the results from the first page that has been returned:

```
results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
for item in results['items']:
        results = sp.next(results['items'])
        track = item['track']
        label = track['artists'][0]['name'] + ' - ' + track['name'] 
        print (label)
```

Using some of the other examples on how to iterate through playlists that have multiple pages, I have placed a while statement to go to the next page (if one exists)

```
results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
for item in results['items']:
    while results['next']:
        results = sp.next(results['items'])
        track = item['track']
        label = track['artists'][0]['name'] + ' - ' + track['name'] 
        print (label)
```

But this doesn't work, I get the following error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

This is what the get user tracks structure looks like from the Spotify API

```
{
  "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks?offset=0&limit=50",
  "items": []
  "limit": 50,
  "next": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks?offset=50&limit=50",
  "offset": 0,
  "previous": null,
  "total": 414
}
```

Inside the items array there are tracks which I have committed because there are too many.

Can someone explain how to correctly go through to the next pages and continue the for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
tracks = results['items']
while results['next']:
    results = sp.next(results)
    tracks.extend(results['items'])

for track in tracks:
    print(track['track']['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try:

```
for item in results['tracks']['items']:
    while results['tracks']['next']:
        results = sp.next(results['tracks']['items'])
        track = item['track']
        label = track['artists'][0]['name'] + ' - ' + track['name'] 
        print (label)
```

Comment: Hey Pavel, this doesnt match the JSON structure. I have update my post to include what the structure looks like that might help.